# Not able to save in JPEG format

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save

[image]

There in no option of saving a file in JPEG format. suggest please

Comment: you should not use the 'save as' dialog but the 'save for web' or 'export' dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File > Export then choose export as JPEG.

Make sure you tick the box that says "Use Artboards" otherwise illustrator will crop the JPEG to the size of the objects you have in your file and not to the size of your artboard.